# How to write data into an Excel file in C++

Tags: c++, excel

I am programming with Microsoft Visual studio 2012 C++.
My professor asks me to put the result of my program into an excel file instead of a text file. Because it is easier for others to understand.
Is there some interface I can use in my C++ program to directly generate an excel file and put the data in it?

Comment: The easiest way is to write down a CSV file and import it in EXCEL. May not what you are looking for, though...

Comment: For more features like cell formatting etc there exist libraries for C++ also like libXl. http://www.libxl.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to use a third party library or automation, and you need some kind of formatting (colors, fonts, etc...) you can simply create a open office xml.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Office_2003_XML_formats

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. I found another problem when using XML. For example, my original data is 20570121.414067134, but when I put this number into a .xml file, it automatically become 20570100. I have tried to let it output 8 decimal places, but the number just become 20570100.00000000. Do you know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Have you writed something like this: <Cell ss:Index="3"><Data ss:Type="Number">20570121.414067101</Data></Cell> ? (note the ss:Type)

Comment: No, I didn't directly write the number, I wrote like: <Cell ss:Index="3"><Data ss:Type="Number">data</Data></Cell> with data = 20570121.414067101 in my C++ program

Comment: when you open the xml file on a text editor, do you have the 20570121.414067101 ? Maybe your problem is with the decimal separator and you local definitions.

Answer (score 3):

Would your professor accept a csv file? This is a Character Separated Value; often a comma is used as the delimiter although Excel will accept tab characters too. Excel can load these things automatically and splits the input into separate rows and columns. I suspect that's what the professor is after.

Otherwise, using the Component Object Model (COM) for Excel is another route. But that's far more involved.

Answer (score 3):

I have been using this library in Linux:

https://github.com/jmcnamara/libxlsxwriter.git

It works well, and of course, it is fast.

The 'use csv' advice stops working as soon as you need more than one sheet in the file, as it is my case.

Answer (score 2):

There is a portable C/C++ library called XLSX I/O that can write to .xlsx files, without even having Excel installed.
See: https://github.com/brechtsanders/xlsxio

Answer (score 2):

On Windows you can use [ODBC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/microsoft/microsoft-odbc-desktop-database-drivers?view=sql-server-2017), which allow working with Excel sheets as regular database tables. It only deals with data though, not formatting, diagrams etc. Standard ODBC driver supports only xls files; to create xlsx file Microsoft Access 2010+ Database Engine Redistributable must be installed.

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <sqlext.h>

WCHAR szDSN[] = L"Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls)};DSN='';CREATE_DB=\"C:\\test\\newfile.xls\";DBQ=C:\\test\\newfile.xls;READONLY=0;";

BOOL ExecuteSql(HDBC hDbc, LPWSTR query){

    RETCODE rc;
    HSTMT hStmt;
    WCHAR bufstate[10]=L"";
    WCHAR buferr[1024]=L"";
    SQLINTEGER i;
    SQLSMALLINT cch;
    BOOL result;

    wprintf(L">%s\n", query);

    /* Prepare SQL query */
    rc = SQLAllocStmt(hDbc,&hStmt);

    if(!SQL_SUCCEEDED(rc)){
        wprintf(L"SQLAllocStmt failed\n");
        return FALSE;
    }

    rc = SQLPrepare(hStmt, query, SQL_NTS);   

    if(!SQL_SUCCEEDED(rc)){
        wprintf(L"SQLPrepare failed\n");
        SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT,hStmt);
        return FALSE;
    }

    /* Excecute the query */
    rc = SQLExecute(hStmt); 

    if (SQL_SUCCEEDED(rc)) {
        wprintf(L"SQL Success\n");
        result = TRUE;
    }
    else{       
        SQLGetDiagRec(SQL_HANDLE_STMT,hStmt,1,bufstate,&i,buferr,sizeof(buferr)/sizeof(buferr[0]),&cch);
        wprintf(L"SQL Error. Code: %d; Message: %s\n",i,buferr);    
        result = FALSE;
    }

    SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT,hStmt);
    return result;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{    
setlocale(LC_ALL,"Russian");
HENV    hEnv;
HDBC    hDbc;

/* ODBC API return status */
RETCODE rc;

int     iConnStrLength2Ptr;
WCHAR    szConnStrOut[256];

/* Allocate an environment handle */
rc = SQLAllocEnv(&hEnv);
/* Allocate a connection handle */
rc = SQLAllocConnect(hEnv, &hDbc);

/* Connect to the database */
rc = SQLDriverConnect(hDbc, NULL, (WCHAR*)szDSN, 
    SQL_NTS, (WCHAR*)szConnStrOut, 
    255, (SQLSMALLINT*)&iConnStrLength2Ptr, SQL_DRIVER_NOPROMPT);

if (SQL_SUCCEEDED(rc)) 
{
    wprintf(L"Successfully connected to database. Data source name: \n  %s\n", 
        szConnStrOut);  

    ExecuteSql(hDbc,L"CREATE TABLE [Test] ([Name] TEXT, [Surname] TEXT)");  
    ExecuteSql(hDbc,L"INSERT INTO [Test] VALUES ('John','Smith')");    
}
else
{
    wprintf(L"Couldn't connect to %s.\n",szDSN);
}

/* Disconnect and free up allocated handles */
SQLDisconnect(hDbc);
SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, hDbc);
SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, hEnv);

getchar();
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Modern EXCEL versions can read a variety of formats, not only the native EXCEL format, and some of them are easier to produce than others.

You can produce native EXCEL files using *automation*, but that is difficult, cumbersome and fragile (sometimes it stops working without a reason).

If you simply want to fill a few cells the easiest way is to write a CSV file.

If you want more control on the format or layout of your sheets you can use the Excel 2003 XML format. Just create a template of the file as you like, and use it to create your own: it is plain XML, relatively simple to understand.

Answer (score 1):

I am late to the party but I tried few of the above solutions and this is what seems to be working well for me. I have taken inspiration from other sites too.

First piece was to use MS Component Object Model (COM). Refer this paper - [Excel C++](https://personalpages.manchester.ac.uk/staff/Andrew.Hazel/EXCEL_C++.pdf)

```
#import "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\OFFICE14\mso.dll"  \
rename_namespace("Office2003") \
rename("RGB","RGBmso") \
rename("DocumentProperties","DocumentPropertiesmso")
#import "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\VBA\VBA6\VBE6EXT.olb"  \
rename_namespace("VBE6")
#pragma warning (disable:4278)
#import "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\EXCEL.EXE" \
exclude("IFont", "IPicture") \
rename("RGB","RGBxl") \
rename("DialogBox", "DlgBoxxl")
```

Next create Excel pointers for Excel::_ApplicationPtr, Excel::_WorkbookPtr, and Excel::_WorksheetPtr

Initialize your dll using AfxInitExtensionModule()

Create a pointer to Excel Range - Excel::RangePtr. This is what is used to access data at cell level.

Expose APIs to your client code for reading and writing. 
This is a good guide to do that
https://github.com/jmcnamara/libxlsxwriter
[CSpreadSheet](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1636/CSpreadSheet-A-Class-to-Read-and-Write-to-Excel-an)

For performance POV, I was able to write ~33k records in 155 seconds.