# Bug writing into Excel file - C++

Tags: c++, excel, memory, fstream

When I send a variable into Excel it changes its value. It just happens with excel. It also just happens when the variable is stored in a container. I guess it is more clear if you see the code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<array>
#include<vector>
#include<fstream>

const int aSize{ 150000 };
std::array<double, aSize> anArray{};

int main(void)
{
    double aValue{ 0.00000005467 };
    std::vector<double> aVector;
    for (int i = 0; i < aSize; ++i)
    {
        anArray[i] = aValue;
        aVector.push_back(aValue);
    }

    std::ofstream fileOne, fileTwo, fileThree, fileFour, fileFive;
    fileOne.open("array.xls"); 
    fileTwo.open("array.txt");
    fileThree.open("vector.xls");
    fileFour.open("vector.txt");
    fileFive.open("value.xls");

    fileOne << anArray[0];
    fileTwo << anArray[0];
    fileThree << aVector[0];
    fileFour << aVector[0];
    fileFive << aValue;

    std::cout << aValue << "\n" << anArray[0] << "\n" << aVector[0];

    return 0;
}
```

All I do is populate a vector and an array. If I print the value of the variable I get the expected value. If I send it into a .txt I get the expected value. If I send just the value into Excel I get the expected value.

It all just breakes down when I send the value from the containers into Excel. Why can this be happening?

Comment: Maybe I'm off the ball here, but can you actually just write to an `.xls` file just using simple (textual) output? I thought `.xls` files were rather more complicated than that.

Comment: @Adrian I have tried .xls, .xlsx, .csv. They all give me the same result

Comment: I just tried your code and I get the same (correct) value in all five files. What compiler/platform are you using?

Comment: Do you get the same order of magnitude in all of them? Are them all 5.4e-8? Because I still get 5.4, but e-5.

Comment: @PhysicsPDF you cannot naively write text to an Excel file (.xls, or .xlsx).

Comment: @Jabberwocky Then why does it work when I send aVale, instead of array[0]? And I get the same issue with .csv

Comment: @Jabberwocky I thought that too but, when I do it and open it in Excel, I get a warning that it's non-standard, but the a displayed worksheet with the single value (5.4e-8) in cell [0,0].

Comment: Maybe there's an issue with interpreting the decimal point (dot/comma mismatch)? Check your "locale" setting for Excel and/or C++ environment.

Comment: @Adrian if that was causing the problem, wouldn't it happen for both aValue, and vector[0]/array[0]? It only happens when I send directly from the containers. Regarding the compiler/platform I am using the last version of Visual Studio on windows.

Comment: I guess it probably would! Maybe try making your `aSize` (a lot) smaller to see if it's a memory issue?

Comment: You can write a `.csv` file and read that into excel. Probably why it works at all is .csv, .xls ... are all associated with excel. When excel opens the file and sees the content of the file is not a real xls it may fall back and try to read it as a csv.

Comment: @Adrian I was so convinced it had to be a memory problem. I am working with a much larger array. It never occured to me it could be the dot/comma mismatch, weirdly enough it only happens with container and not with the value. Setting both to the same convention fixed my problem. Add you comment as an Answer and I will mark it as accepted.

Comment: It still puzzles my why it just happened when sending directly from the container, but I have been struggling for so long that I wont look into that now. It is probably something silly I am doing.

Comment: @PhysicsPDF OK, as you were so insistent!

Comment: It might help somebody in the future. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What seems likely to be the problem here is the way the `Excel` is interpreting the (formatted) numerical output from your `c++` program. Even though the text may be correct (from the point of view of the `cout` function) it may not have the 'correct' decimal point character in it (i.e. a dot instead of a comma, or *vice versa*).

Solution: Make sure that `Excel` is set to use the same "locale" as the default `c++` locale, or set the `c++` locale to whatever `Excel` is using.

Comment: But what bothers me here is why the `cout` call appears to format differently for your container objects; I would have thought that all five values given to `<<` would resolve to straight `double` values?

Answer (score 2):

The MS-XLS file format is not a simple text file. You cannot simply put text into it and expect it to show up correctly. You would need more code and/or specialized libraries to interact with it.

See [the suggestions here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20261034/how-to-write-data-into-an-excel-file-in-c).

Comment: `https://github.com/jmcnamara/libxlsxwriter.git` is a good writer. However it does not let you add data to an existing excel file.