# C++: Create a Plot Graph Using a Console Application

Tags: c++, console-application

I have a C++ application I am using for path planning. The path planning works absolutely great, but I would like a way to visualize the points found in the path in my console application.

I can easily get all my points X and Y positions, and I quickly wrote something up to print them to a comma separated file.

`

```
    for (auto node : path.Path) {

        if (node == NULL)
            break;

        AStarHandler.FindPos(node->GetIDLong(), XPos, YPos);

        cs_log_printf("TestGraph", 0, ",%d,%d",
            XPos, YPos);
    }
```

`

This prints me out a nice comma seperated file I can throw into excel and display the graph.

[Excel Map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Bvjb.png)

And I could also easily print this out in the console application.

[Positions printed in console app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Obew.png)

Are there any avalible methods to cut out the middle man of printing this to a CSV and putting it into an excel file.

I would like to just display these points on the console in a graphical view.

I put it into the csv file. I dont wannt to take that extra step.

Comment: You could use an library that generates excel directly in c++: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20261034/how-to-write-data-into-an-excel-file-in-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20261034/how-to-write-data-into-an-excel-file-in-c) I have used: [https://github.com/jmcnamara/libxlsxwriter](https://github.com/jmcnamara/libxlsxwriter) in past c++ projects.

Comment: You can either right directly to .csv by making sure that it follows it's format with comma separation. Or you can use something like Graphviz and write to their format.

Comment: drecherjm and Sailanarmo, I want to take the CSV and excel out of it competely and put it straight into a graphical illistration on my console app, I was only showing those to display that I already have the coordinates and paths figured out. Sailanarmo I will try the Graphviz

Comment: My idea was to in your c++ code generate an xlsx file which has the graph already in it. You could spawn Excel directly from your c++ code to show that graph. In any case in your console application you will most likely need to either open up a GUI window or spawn a GUI application.

Comment: There are some plotting libs in the end of this list of recommended opensource libs: [https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/links/libs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/links/libs)

Comment: @PatrickG, that will take a lot more graphical knowledge if you want to display a graph from the console. OpenCV or even OpenGL (I think it would have to be this) would be the way to directly render something from your console. However, that is going to be a lot more difficult to achieve rather than writing to a .csv file and displaying it from there. I could be wrong on that. But OpenGL is probably what you are really looking for.